# Convergence of an improper integral involving the difference of roots

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, improper-integrals

I have to study the convergence of this integral:

$\int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{\sqrt x - \sqrt[5]{x}} dx$

I rewrite it as:

$\int_{0}^{a} f (x)  dx + \int_{a}^{1} f (x)  dx$ (with $0<a<1$)

in order to deal with the problems in 0 and 1 separately.

For the first one, since $ \sqrt x = o(\sqrt [5] x )$ , for $x \rightarrow 0$, it should be right to say that $f(x) \sim \frac{1}{- \sqrt[5]{x}}$, so it converges

As for the other (here's my doubt), I apply a change of variable (t=1-x) in order to obtain:

$\int_{a}^{1} f (x)  dx = \int_{0}^{1-a} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-t} - \sqrt[5]{1-t}} dt$

Then, using the relation  $(1+x)^{b} \sim 1 + b x $ (for $ x \rightarrow 0$), I rewrite f (t) as:

$\frac{1}{(1-\frac {1}{2}t) - (1--\frac {1}{5}t)} $

so that

$ \int_{0}^{1-a} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-t} - \sqrt[5]{1-t}} dt \sim  \int_{0}^{1-a} -\frac{10}{3t} dt$

which diverges  (negatively)

My question: Am I overcomplicating the whole thing, especially the second integral? I feel there should be a faster way for it but at the moment I'm not able to find it.

Comment: For the divergence it should be enough to mention that $x=1$ is a regular single root of the denominator. If you want to remain in the given level of detail, I do not see how you could shorten it.

Comment: Ok, so what I did is the right way and, in this case, there' s no shortcut (I mean, something as simple/fast as in the first integral)? I don't know why but I thought I was missing something obvious :D

Comment: By the way, thanks for your answer

Answer (score 2):

We are now examining the following integral:
$$
\int_{0}^{1} \frac {1}{{x}^{1 / 5} - {x}^{1 / 2}} \text {d} x.
$$
To begin with, we let $x \mapsto {x}^{10}$. So ${x}^{1 / 5} \mapsto {x}^{2}$, ${x}^{1 / 2} \mapsto {x}^{5}$, and $\text {d} x \mapsto 10 {x}^{9} \text {d} x$; accordingly,
$$
\int_{0}^{1} \frac {1}{{x}^{1 / 5} - {x}^{1 / 2}} \text {d} x = 10 \int_{0}^{1} \frac {{x}^{7}}{1 - {x}^{3}} \text {d} x.
$$
Let $x = 1 - h$. As $x \to {1}_{-}$, $h \to {0}_{+}$, and
$$
\begin{align}
\frac {{x}^{7}}{1 - {x}^{3}} \sim \frac {1}{1 - {x}^{3}}
& = \frac {1}{1 - {\left( 1 - h \right)}^{3}} \\
& = \frac {1}{1 - \left( 1 - 3 h + \mathcal {O} \left( {h}^{2} \right) \right)} = \frac {1}{3 h} \cdot \frac {1}{1 + \mathcal {O} \left( h \right)} \sim \frac {1}{3 h}.
\end{align}
$$
Since we know that
$$
\int_{0}^{a} \frac {1}{x} \text {d} x
$$
diverges for all $a > 0$, the given integral must diverge.

Comment: I don't understand way you switch the roots in the very first integral.

Comment: @user_unknown Switching the roots just reverses the sign. I know that your original integral is negative, and that my variant is positive. I generally prefer to stay positive. :)

Comment: Ok, got it. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

We can use that

$$A^5-B^5=(A-B)(A^4+A^3B+A^2B^2+AB^3+B^4)$$

to show that

$$\int_{0}^{1} \frac {1}{\sqrt[5]x - \sqrt x} \;d x \ge \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\sqrt[5]{x^4}}{x- x^2\sqrt x} \;d x$$

which is problematic at $x=1$ indeed

$$ \frac{\sqrt[5]{x^4}}{x- x^2\sqrt x} = \frac{\sqrt[5]{x^4}}{x}\frac{1}{1- x\sqrt x}$$

and by $x=1-u$  the second factor becomes

$$\frac{1}{1- x\sqrt x}=\frac{1}{1- (1-u)\sqrt {1-u}}=\frac{1}{1-\sqrt {1-u}+u\sqrt {1-u}}\sim \frac 1u$$

which is problematic at $u=0$.

Comment: Nice one, thank you.

Comment: @user_unknown You are welcome! Bye